# Different behaviour when using context class and contextmananger method decorator in Python

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, exception, try-catch, python-multithreading

I get different behaviour in the following two scenarios when trying to use Python (3.5)'s context manager. I'm trying to handle `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions to my threaded program gracefully by using a proper shutdown procedure in combination with a context manager, but it seems like I can't get this to work in the second case and I can't see why not.

Common to both cases is a generic "job" task that uses threading:

```
import threading
class Job(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        self.active = True

        while self.active:
            continue

    def stop(self):
        self.active = False
```

Once started with `start` (a method provided by the `threading.Thread` parent class, which calls `run` internally), it can be stopped by calling `stop`.

The first way I tried to do this was to use the built-in `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods so as to take advantage of Python's `with` statement support:

```
class Context(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.active = False

    def __enter__(self):
        print("Entering context")
        self.job = Job()
        self.job.start()
        return self.job

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print("Exiting context")
        self.job.stop()
        self.job.join()
        print("Job stopped")
```

I run it using the following code:

```
with Context():
    while input() != "stop":
        continue
```

This waits until the user types "stop" and presses enter. If during this loop the user instead presses `Ctrl+C` to create a `KeyboardInterrupt`, the `__exit__` method is still called:

```
Entering context
^CExiting context
Job stopped
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp2.py", line 48, in <module>
    while input() != "stop":
KeyboardInterrupt
```

The second way I tried to do this was to create a function using the `@contextmanager` decorator:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def job_context():
    print("Entering context")
    job = Job()
    job.start()
    yield job
    print("Exiting context")
    job.stop()
    job.join()
    print("Job stopped")
```

I again run it using the `with` statement:

```
with job_context():
    while input() != "stop":
        continue
```

But when I run it, and press `Ctrl+C`, the code after the `yield` - the equivalent of the `__exit__` method in the first example, is not executed. Instead, the Python script continues to run in the infinite loop. To stop the program I have to press `Ctrl+C` a second time, at which point the code after `yield` is not executed:

```
Entering context
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp2.py", line 42, in <module>
    while input() != "stop":
KeyboardInterrupt
^CException ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 1288, in _shutdown
    t.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 1054, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 1070, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

You can see the `^C` symbols where I pressed `Ctrl+C` to create the interrupts. What's different about the second case that it doesn't perform the shutdown code equivalent to `__exit__` in the first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

> If an unhandled exception occurs in the block, it is reraised inside
>   the generator at the point where the yield occurred. Thus, you can use
>   a `try`...`except`...`finally` statement to trap the error (if any), or
>   ensure that some cleanup takes place.

In your case, this would look like:

```
@contextmanager
def job_context():
    print("Entering context")
    job = Job()
    job.start()
    try:
        yield job
    finally:
        print("Exiting context")
        job.stop()
        job.join()
        print("Job stopped")
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you. It seems to me to be a little counter-intuitive that the exception is thrown in the method with the yield command. Surely the exception should be thrown where it was produced?

Comment: What do you mean *"where it was produced"*?

Comment: The `KeyboardException` occurs in the main loop, so it is strange to me that it is reraised in the generator.

Comment: @Sean how else would you be able to catch and handle it in your context manager?

Comment: Ah yes. That makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: There shouldn't be a `raise` inside the `finally` block. In the case no exception is generated from inside the `with` block, this `raise` will not have any exception to re-raise. Just leave it out and if there is exception, the exception will correctly propagate to the caller since you didn't catch it